# Accessing Shoothill API in R/ R Studio

Tags: json, r, api, rstudio

Hi I am trying to access the Floodhill Flood Alert API in R using R studio.
http://www.shoothill.com/floodapi/

I'm not entirely sure how I login with the API key I have and then call the API.

I have had success with calling an API using a different API, e.g.

```
library(jsonlite)
jsondata <- fromJSON("http://api.wunderground.com/api/c86b0e891d592775/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json")#access api
names(jsondata)
summary(jsondata)
```

Help on accessing the Shoothill Flood Alert API would be much appreciated!

Comment: https://apifa.shoothill.com/

Comment: takes a while to get an API key. see the non-answer-answer below for some guidance until then.

Comment: Thanks - if you able to help that would be appreciated. I am finding I get the principle of RCurl but the implementation a little more tricky.

Comment: got confirmation of API key 5 mins ago. will take a look in the AM (well, AM for Maine).

Answer (score 1):

This technically isn't a full R answer but the example they give on the API provider page is 100% doable in R with the `RCurl` package:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$apiKey = '<Your API Key>';
$url = 'https://apifa.shoothill.com/Account/APILogin/';

$postinfo = "apikey=".$apiKey."&persist=false";

$cookie_file_path = dirname(__FILE__) . "cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);

$out = curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://apifa.shoothill.com/API/Floods");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: application/json'));

$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $html;
return $html;
?>
```

OmegaHat has a rly detailed [explanation](http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/philosophy.html) of how to use `RCurl` and you should be able to translate the above pretty well after going through it.

Comment: You should NEVER set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` to 0. It's a gaping security hole.

Comment: That's a cut and paste from their site